# how to convert india number to arabic number?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

i'm trying to make calls from my app, but it seems i can't because the numbers are in india format (example : ٩٦٦٥٩٥٨٤٨٨٨٢) and to make it work , I have to convert this string to arabic format (example : 966595848882)

my code :

```
NSString *cleanedString = [[ContactInfo componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-+()"] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:cleanedString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `NSNumberFormatter` with the appropriate locale. For example:

```
NSString *indianNumberString = @"٩٦٦٥٩٥٨٤٨٨٨٢";
NSNumberFormatter *nf1 = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"hi_IN"];
[nf1 setLocale:locale];

NSNumber *newNum = [nf1 numberFromString:indianNumberString];
NSLog(@"new: %@", newNum);
```

This prints "966595848882".

I'm not 100% certain on the locale identifier above-- `hi_IN` should be "Hindi India". If that's not correct, use `[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]` to get a list of all known locale identifiers, and find one that's more appropriate.

**Update**: in order to pad this out to nine digits (or however many you want), convert back to an `NSString` using standard `NSString` formatting:

```
NSString *paddedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%09ld", [newNum integerValue]];
```

The format `%09ld` will zero-pad out to nine digits.

It's also possible to do this using the same number formatter, converting the number above back into a string while requiring 9 digits. This also gives at least nine digits, with zero padding if necessary:

```
[nf1 setMinimumIntegerDigits:9];
NSString *reverseConvert = [nf1 stringFromNumber:newNum];
```

Comment: it worked,thanks. But NSNumber deleting zeros from beginning is there anything i can do ?(please **notice** : sometimes the number start with zero , sometimes start with nine or eight ,EX : 920000001)

Comment: I don't speak the language, but I find this method very interesting. +1.